# JTextArea alignment

Tags: java, swing

Any method available to place the `JTextArea` to the right of the `JPanel`?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Maybe if you posted some of your code it would help or a screenshot of your application

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in the right hand side *within* the `JPanel`?

If so, you could construct the `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` as its layout manager, then add the `JTextArea` with

```
panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

It's possible that `BorderLayout` isn't what you want though, depending on the right of your controls. There are many options available. I suggest you read a [layout tutorial](http://www.j2ee.me/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more details.

If that's not what you mean, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the [`LayoutManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) that your `JPanel` uses, not the `JTextArea` itself. Unless you specify a `LayoutManager` when creating your `JPanel`, it will be using [`FlowLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a spacer component to the JPanel first which will push the text area to the right.  The code to create such a component is: Box.createHorizontalGlue();